# How ECDH algorithm selects modulus value?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I am curious to know how an ECDH algorithms select a module value, if both ends A & B can generate same shared key using the public key of each other ? 
If I understood DH correctly, both A and B send each other their public key. Then at each side the ECDH operation takes as parameter self ECC key and the public key of the other party. So, I'm not clear how they shared the modulus value?

From wikipedia:

```
Alice and Bob agree to use a modulus p = 23 and base g = 5 (which is a primitive root modulo 23).
Alice chooses a secret integer a = 6, then sends Bob A = g^a mod p
A = 56 mod 23 = 8
Bob chooses a secret integer b = 15, then sends Alice B = g^b mod p
B = 515 mod 23 = 19
Alice computes s = Ba mod p
s = 196 mod 23 = 2
Bob computes s = Ab mod p
s = 815 mod 23 = 2
Alice and Bob now share a secret (the number 2).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is plain DH, not ECDH. There's no Elliptic Curve here.

For plain DH, the modulus should be a safe prime $p$ and the generator should generate the $q=(p-1)/2$ order subgroup. Unlike RSA, these numbers are public and can be shared between all users - one can use standardised ones for example the [RFC 5114](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5114) ones for SSL/TLS (which are actually NIST standardised), or one can pick one's own parameters.

Whoever initiates the connection (sends the first message) could start off by sending the group parameters she wants to use or, in the case of SSl/TLS, IKE etc. simply giving the name of the standardised group. If it's not a standardised group, the other party should then check that the $p$ in question really is a safe prime and that $g$ generates a group of the correct order. Alternatively, if you're implementing an application you can just pick a group and hard-code it in your application.

For ECDH the situation is this: for security reasons, do not choose your own groups (except if your name is Dan Bernstein). Pick one of the standard ones to avoid all kinds of nastiness.

Comment: For ECDH do you mean that the group parameter of elliptic curve e.g. secp192 gives information in generating modulus value ?

Comment: @hab In the case of curves over $Fp$ the calculations are performed modulus $p$ and $p$ is *part of* the domain parameters specified by secp192.